# Good introductory book for self-studying quasigroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, self-learning, quasigroups

I'm looking for an undergraduate or beginning graduate level text from which to self-learn quasigroup theory. An emphasis on using quasigroups to understand the structure of groups would be appreciated. I prefer texts that are leisurely and systematic. I like having only a few examples, but those examples worked out in great detail.

Comment: I don't believe that quasigroups are studied at the undergraduate level.

Comment: Indeed often they are not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Bruck and Belousov were mentioned already, I add the following two references:

- [*Quasigroups and loops: introduction* by H. O. Pflugfelder](https://books.google.it/books/about/Quasigroups_and_loops.html?id=MQbvAAAAMAAJ) is a very good book,
- [*An Introduction to Quasigroups and Their Representations* by J. D. H. Smith](https://books.google.it/books?id=NfWlUZSOwSkC) is a very good book also but is not easy.

Answer (score 3):

Bruck R.H.: A Survey of Binary Systems. Springer-Verlag, Berlin-Gottingen-Heidelberg, 1966.

Moreover, there is a good book

Belousov V.D.: Foundations of the theory of quasigroups and loops, Moscow, 1967,

but as you see, it is only in Russian